# Set a <select> HTML tag using $scope - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an HTML `<select>` tag:

```
Document type <select class="form-control" name="document_type" ng-model="document_type"
                            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" required>
```

I have saved an `options` variable in the scope of my model:

```
$scope.options = [{
                        label : '',
                        value : ''
                    },  {
                        label : "ID card",
                        value : "ID card"
                    }, {
                        label : 'Passport',
                        value : 'Passport'
                    }, {
                        label : 'Driving license',
                        value : 'Driving license'
                    } ];
```

In this way I have the following field:

[image]

My target is to set the `document_type` 'variable' using the `$scope`:

```
$scope.document_type = "Passport"
```

but it does not work and the `<select>` field stays blank.

Comment: Is the number of document types known and finite?

Comment: Yes it is. There are just the three choices that you can see in my picture.

Comment: See my solution just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is actually setting `document_type` to an object with `label` and `value` properties, but you are trying to assign the default value as a string.

If you want `document_type` to be a string rather than an object, you should change your `ng-options` clause slightly.  instead of `opt as opt.label ...` use `opt.value as opt.label ...`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = [{
    label: '',
    value: ''
  }, {
    label: "ID card",
    value: "ID card"
  }, {
    label: 'Passport',
    value: 'Passport'
  }, {
    label: 'Driving license',
    value: 'Driving license'
  }];
  
  $scope.document_type="Passport";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Document type
  <select class="form-control" name="document_type" ng-model="document_type" 
          ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options" required></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following plunkr..

https://plnkr.co/edit/CLue567fPpxp5gXMobcP?p=preview

```
<select class="form-control" name="document_type" ng-model="document_type"
                            ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options" ng-change="func()"  required></select>
```

.

```
$scope.func=function(){
     alert($scope.document_type.value);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="document_type" 
   ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options">
</select>

<div>{{ document_type }}</div>

 $scope.options = [{
    label: '',
    value: ''
  }, {
    label: "ID card",
    value: "ID card"
  }, {
    label: 'Passport',
    value: 'Passport'
  }, {
    label: 'Driving license',
    value: 'Driving license'
  }];

  $scope.document_type = $scope.options[2];
```

In your question you are setting the text to your selected option, but in your actual implementation you adding an JSON formatted data as ng-option. If you set proper format data, it will get selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/svpjgm8s/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context where you make this assignment, you may need to include after it the following invocation:

```
 $scope.$apply() ;
```

Try this.